# Pass parameter from app.xaml.cs to MainPage

Tags: c#

My application is launched by a protocol like my-app://path?param1=123"&"param2=abc .

I succeeded to get values from query parameters in app.xaml.cs's OnActivated handler.

But I can not override onNavigatedTo handler of MainPage class. VS says onNavigatedTo is not found.

How can I receive parameters on MainPage?

```
        protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs e) {
            base.OnActivated(e);

            string argMessage = string.Empty;
            if (e.Kind == ActivationKind.Protocol)
            {
                ProtocolActivatedEventArgs eventArgs = e as ProtocolActivatedEventArgs;
                Debug.WriteLine("Procol URI="+eventArgs.Uri);
                argMessage = eventArgs.Uri.Query;
            }
            Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

            if (rootFrame == null)
            {
                rootFrame = new Frame();
                rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;
                Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
            }
            else
            {
                if (e.Kind == ActivationKind.Protocol)
                {
                    rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), argMessage);
                }
            }
            if (rootFrame.Content == null)
            {
                    rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), argMessage);
            }
            Window.Current.Activate();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send any kind of objects in navigation function as param.

I can see it in your code itself,

```
rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), argMessage);
```

Here `"argMessage"`  is a object which you want send i guess.

IF you want send any other object , just pass it instead of `argMessage`.

And receive it in your mainpage like this

```
 var parameters = e.Parameter;
```

Here is some samples to understand it better

[Navigation Between Pages With Passing Data On Windows 10](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4e4e9d/navigation-between-pages-with-passing-data-on-windows-10/)

[Passing complex object between classes in UWP](https://learnwithbddevs.wordpress.com/2016/11/26/passing-complex-object-between-classes-in-uwp/)

Hope this helps.

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks but I can not override onNavigatedTo().

Comment: Finally, I found solution. Adding "using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;" is the answer. Anyway, thank you Noorul.